# Lily Pad mp3, nested loops with timing and play randomly choosen mp3, coding problem

Tags: programming, sketch, timing

The best way to explain my problem is in form of code...

```
    const int ringerPin = A0;
    const int offhook = A4;
    const int onhook = A5;

    void setup(){
    pinMode(ringerPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(offhook, INPUT);
    pinMode(onhook, INPUT);
    randomSeed(analogRead(0));

  }

  int randCall = random(60000, 3600000); // generate a random number between 1 min and 60 min

//ring every 1 to 60 minutes if the phone is down (hookon) and dont ring if the phone is picked up (no hookon)
void loop()
{
  if (digitalRead(hookon) == HIGH)

void loop(){
delay(randCall);

      //i dont know how to let this loop below here run for 30 seconds.
 void loop()
    {
      //turn audio off - i dont know how to.
    for(int x = 0; x < 15; x++){
      digitalWrite(ringerPin, HIGH);   
      delay(50);                           
      digitalWrite(ringerPin, LOW);   
      delay(80); 
    }
    delay(2500);
    }
  else
    //play one randomly choosen audiofile out of 10 - i dont know how to
}
}
```

Maybe you can give me some suggestions to my coding problems.?
I wrote them inside the code descriptions.

Comment: WHy do you have 3 definitions of `loop()` in your code, is it a copy/paste issue?

Answer (score 1):

Halo, thank you for ansering anything.. I got the loop loop loop thing now runin..

So its about playing an Audiofile if hookon == LOW ........ check it out :-)

The code now looks like this.

```
const int ringerPin = A0;
const int offhook = A4;
const int onhook = A5;
double beginRing = -40000;

void setup(){
    pinMode(ringerPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(offhook, INPUT);
    pinMode(onhook, INPUT);
    randomSeed(analogRead(0)); // this starts Arduino's random number generator
}

int randCall = random(60000, 3600000); // generate a random number between 1 min and 60 min

//ring every 1 to 60 minutes if the phone is down (hookon) and dont ring if the phone is picked up (no hookon)
void loop()
{
  if (digitalRead(hookon) == HIGH){
    delay (randCall);
    beginRing = Time.elapsedTime;
    while(Time.elapsedTime - beginRing <= 30000 && digitalRead(hookon) == HIGH){
      //turn any audio off???
      for(int x = 0; x < 15; x++){
        digitalWrite(ringerPin, HIGH);   // turn the solenoid on (HIGH is the voltage level)
        delay(50);                           // wait for 50 msec
        digitalWrite(ringerPin, LOW);    // turn the solenoid off by making the voltage LOW
        delay(80);                          // wait for 50 msec
      }
      delay(2500);
    }
  }
  if(Time.elapsedTime - beginRing <= 30000){
    //play one randomly choosen audiofile out of 10
  }
}
```

So, now its about to stop any sound if the hookon is HIGH and to play the randomly choosen file 1 out of 10 if the hookon is LOW (its in the code as description...there i need the right comands)